# I'm making a flashcard using JS and i encounteres a problem when i click the save button the card appears but after that there is problem?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making an flashcard using javascript and everything is working fine but when I press the save button to save the card there is error. it should display the question and after a click event it should show the answer of that card clicked but there is an error. also my browser storing also doesn't work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: , sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: #092d4a;
}



button {
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #092d4a;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #092d4a;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;

}

.nav button {
  font-family: inherit;
}

.create-card {
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.create-card textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 2px solid #092d4a;
}

.create-card button {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid #092d4a;
}

.flashcards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0px 17px;
}

.flashcard {
  width: 370px;
  height: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); */
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.flashcard h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;

}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .flashcard {
      margin: auto;
  }

  .flashcard {
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
  .create-card {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .flashcard {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <h1> Saved Flashcards</h1>
            <button class="btn1">Add New Card</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="create-card">
        <p>
            <h2 style="color: black;text-align: center;">Create Flashcard</h2>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="text">Question</label><br>
            <textarea id="question" placeholder="please enter your question here....."></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="text">Answer</label><br>
            <textarea id="answer" placeholder="please place your answer here...."></textarea>
        </p>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button class="btn2" onclick="saveFlashcard()">Save</button>
            <button class="btn3">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="flashcards" id="flashcards"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="brain.js">
const flashcards = document.getElementsByClassName("flashcards")[0];
const createCard = document.getElementsByClassName("create-card")[0];
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const answer = document.getElementById("answer");



// if (localStorage.getItem("stored") == null) {
//     localStorage.setItem("stored", [])
// };


// var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stored"));

// var div = document.createElement("div");
// var h2_question = document.createElement("h2");
// var h2_answer = document.createElement("h2");

// div.className = "flashcard";

// h2_question.setAttribute("style", "border-top:1px solid blue; padding:15px; margin-top:30px");
// h2_question.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("test");

// h2_answer.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center; display:none; color:Blue");
// h2_answer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("test");



// div.appendChild(h2_question);
// div.appendChild(h2_answer);
// flashcards.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", div);


$(".btn1").on("click", function() {
  $(".create-card").show();
});

$(".btn3").on("click", function() {
  $(".create-card").hide();
});



function saveFlashcard() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h2_question = document.createElement("h2");
  var h2_answer = document.createElement("h2");

  div.className = "flashcard";

  h2_question.setAttribute("style", "border-top:1px solid blue; padding:15px; margin-top:30px");
  h2_question.innerHTML = question.value;

  h2_answer.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center; display:none; color:Blue");
  h2_answer.innerHTML = answer.value;

// $(".div").on("click", function() {
//     $(".h2_question").show();
// });

  div.appendChild(h2_question);
  div.appendChild(h2_answer);

  $("div").on("click", function() {
      if (h2_answer.style.display == "none") {
          h2_answer.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          h2_answer.style.display = "none";
      }
  });

  div.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
      div.remove();
  });

  flashcards.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", div);

  question.value = '';
  answer.value = '';

// var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stored"));
// test.push(JSON.stringify([question.value, answer.value]));

};
</script>
```